# Debugging Go wasm : It there a way to bridge an error message appearing in the browser tools to the source in Go?

Tags: typescript, debugging, maps, webassembly, gopherjs

Debugging Go wasm : It there a way to bridge an error message appearing in the browser tools to the source in Go?

For instance If one generates JavaScript code from TS code and runs it an a client-side script in a browser (say Chrome, for instance), then when a error occurs, the link points to the JS file, but by generating also maps in addition to the transpiling, one can get the browser to point to the TS source rather than to the intermediate JS code.

Is there a similar tool to debug wasm in the development phase of an app using Go (via wasm) to generate a front-end app?

Another example is GopherJS: GopherJs translates Go into JS, but using maps one can get the error messages in the browser development tools to point directly to the original Go code rather than to the intermediate JS code.

Comment: By querying `wasm source map` I found this article, which might help lead you in the right direction: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/wasm-debugging-2019/